# Handling out of bounds on a fixed array

Tags: java, arrays

My problem is that for example there's only three passing grades, the user entered then the size of `passGrade` array would only be **three**, same with `failGrade`: if the user entered **two** failing grades then the size of `failGrade` array would only be **two**, in short I want the two arrays to be **of fixed lengths**. In my program it goes *out of bounds*.

Here's the piece of code I'm referring to:

```
Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
int gradeSize=0;
int fixedPassed=0;
int fixedFail=0;
int grades[]=new int[gradeSize];
int passGrade[]=new int[fixedPassed];
int failGrade[]=new int[fixedFail];

System.out.print("Enter Grade Size: ");
gradeSize=input.nextInt();

System.out.println();
System.out.print("Enter Grades: ");
for(int i=0; i<gradeSize; i++)
{
    grades[i]=input.nextInt();
    while(grades[i]<1 || grades[i]>100)
    {
        grades[i]=input.nextInt();
    }
    if(grades[i]>=75)
    { 
        fixedPassed++;
        passGrade[i]=grades[i];

    }
    else if(grades[i]<75)
    {
        fixedFail++;
        failGrade[i]=grades[i];

    }
}
for(int i=0; i<fixedPassed; i++)
{
    System.out.print(passGrade[i]+" ");
}

for(int i=0; i<fixedFail; i++)
{
    System.out.print(failGrade[i]+" ");
}
```

Comment: using `passGrade[i]=grades[i];` if the size of `grades[]` is bigger than `passGrade[]` then of course this will fail.  Also the arrays are initialiazed to zero, so they will be empty.  if you want empty, then try using an `ArrayList` and add to that.

Comment: Arrays are always fixed size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java arrays are fixed size. So you need to get the input, then count the pass/fails. Then create your pass fail arrays and then copy the grades into them. You could do something like this,

```
System.out.print("Enter Grade Size: ");
int gradeSize = input.nextInt();

int passCount = 0;
int grades[]=new int[gradeSize];
System.out.println();
System.out.print("Enter Grades: ");
for (int i = 0; i < gradeSize; i++) {
  grades[i] = input.nextInt();
  if(grades[i] >= 75) { 
    passCount++;
  }
}
int passGrade[] = new int[passCount];
int failGrade[] = new int[grades.length - passCount];
int failCount = passCount = 0;
for (int grade : grades) {
  if (grade >= 75) { 
    passGrade[passCount++] = grade;
  } else {
    failGrade[failCount++] = grade;
  }
}
System.out.println("Passing Grades: " + Arrays.toString(passGrade));
System.out.println("Failing Grades: " + Arrays.toString(failGrade));
```

Comment: Immutable may be too strong a word for arrays. For array _size_, sure.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't know in advance the length of the input, and you don't know in advance how many passed and how many failed, you can't create the arrays before first processing the input.

You should use 3 collections (HashSet, ArrayList, etc ...) to store the input grades, passed grades and failed grades. Once you are done, you can initialize your 3 arrays based on the size() of the collections, and then iterate over the collections to copy their contents to the arrays.